# Missing App Title under App Icon on Device

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest

I have installed the Android App on which I am currently working on my ASUS tablet, running 4.0.3

However, I must have accidentally deleted something in the Manifest.xml, because there is no words below the app icon.  In other words, the app name is not appearing below the app icon on my device, and, as such, it is sorted in the All Apps screen in the wrong place.

Here is the relevant section of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tra.games.mytaboo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.2.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Taboo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.....
```

What am I missing?

Comment: put the XML code of the `<activity>` item of the manifest.

Comment: the label goes in the activity, as it is the activity that is displayed

Comment: @njzk2 If this attribute is not set, the label set for the application as a whole is used instead.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label

Comment: My issue is not within any activity in particular.  Rather, when I start up my tablet, go to the App screen in order to launch my App, there is only an icon, but no title beneath the icon.

Comment: post the rest of your manifest. it is possible the label of the activity is present but empty. (also, what you display is always an activity in particular. the one that has the MAIN LAUNCHER intent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tim, Label of your launcher activity will be displayed.

```
<activity 
    android:label="Taboo" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:name=".activity.LaunchrActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity 
    android:label="Your Name"  <---- here name!
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the setTitle() function from within your Activity. It takes either an int (resource ID) or a CharSequence as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed android:label property. which is set your application name under the icon

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Here I have set to load app name from string.xml file. 
You can set it directly like this too

```
android:label="app name"
```